# How to inject one HttpClient into multiple services

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am building a client of an API. My API is rather big, so I decided to split it into about 5 (private) sub-clients, each covering different part of API. 5 clients are not very comfortable to use, so I'd like to have them under 1 (public) `ApiClient`, which will act as a kind of facade above these 5 clients. The thing is that I probably should share one `HttpClient` between all these sub-clients. As far as I know, I can do something like that:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<SubClient1>(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com"));
```

With the above line, my `SubClient1` will be injected into my public `ApiClient` with the proper `HttpClient` instance already set up with `BaseAddress`. Now, how do I register all 5 of my sub-clients (`SubClient1`, `SubClient2`, `SubClient3`, ...) so that each of them receives the same `HttpClient`?
I think the code below will create 5 `HttpClient` instances:

```cs
services.AddHttpClient<SubClient1>(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com"));
services.AddHttpClient<SubClient2>(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com"));
services.AddHttpClient<SubClient3>(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com"));
services.AddHttpClient<SubClient4>(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com"));
services.AddHttpClient<SubClient5>(c => c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com"));
```

How could I resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using the `HttpClientFactory` and thus delegating the construction on the `HttpClient` to the factory.

Based on the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests

> Registering the client services as shown in the previous code, makes the DefaultClientFactory create a standard HttpClient for each service.

It does this on purpose, so that you can configure your client per service.

In terms of resources you are converted. That was the original purpose of the client factory:

> Each time you get an HttpClient object from the IHttpClientFactory, a new instance is returned. But each HttpClient uses an HttpMessageHandler that's pooled and reused by the IHttpClientFactory to reduce resource consumption, as long as the HttpMessageHandler's lifetime hasn't expired.
>
> Pooling of handlers is desirable as each handler typically manages its own underlying HTTP connections; creating more handlers than necessary can result in connection delays. Some handlers also keep connections open indefinitely, which can prevent the handler from reacting to DNS changes.

If you don't want to use the factory which is the recommended way, you can do something like this:https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2017/10/reusing-httpclient-with-dependency-injection/

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    Uri endPointA = new Uri("http://localhost:58919/"); // this is the endpoint HttpClient will hit
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient()
    {
        BaseAddress = endPointA,
    };

    ServicePointManager.FindServicePoint(endPointA).ConnectionLeaseTimeout = 60000; // sixty seconds

    services.AddSingleton<HttpClient>(httpClient); // note the singleton
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I'd like to use the factory since it's recommended. Do you think that the code that I presented (where I invoke AddHttpClient multiple times) is correct? It would seem that even though I have multiple HttpClients, they'd use correct, managed number of HttpMessageHandlers, right?

Comment: Indeed they would. Your code is pretty much the recommended approach.

Comment: @AthanasiosKataras Hi there, how would this work if you had different api addresses for each "SubClient"?

Answer (score 7):

I don't disagree with @Athanasios Kataras answer. But I don't see the reason why you need to make it into a singleton.

Basically there are 3 ways to dependency inject an http client into a service; Directly, Typed, and Named. What @Athanasios did was directly. But in this scenario I believe a Named HttpClient is the way to go. But you could also just use a typed that gets injected into the subclients assuming the behavior of the client is the same across all subclients.

#### In startup.cs or program.cs (depending on .net 5.0 or .net 6.0)

```
public class Startup
{
    private IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    private IHostEnvironment HostEnvironment { get; set; }

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration, IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
        HostEnvironment = env;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //Named client
        services.AddHttpClient("myapi", c =>
        {
            c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com");
        });

        //Typed client
        services.AddHttpClient<iMyApi, MyApi>(c => 
            c.BaseAddress = new System.Uri("https://myapi.com");
        });
    }
}
```

That adds the HttpClient to the HttpClientFactory, that you can now use in whatever project.

#### Subclient.cs

```
public class SubClient
{
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory httpFactory;
    private readonly HttpClient namedClient;
    private readonly iMyApi typedClient;
    private readonly static string clientName = "myapi";

    public SubClient(IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory, iMyApi myApiClient)
    {
        this.namedClient = httpClientFactory.Create(clientName);
        this.typedClient = myApiClient;
    }
}
```

With the typed client it depends on you creating an implementation that implements the endpoints of your api. The advantage here is that you have a transient client that can be used in any of your services. And you free yourself from what I suspect would be a lot of duplicate code.